# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream with local IPs

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've read similar questions with same error, but nothing matches my problem, because my upstream servers have local IPs.

The server is a proxmox machine with some different vms.
One is for nginx reverse gateway/proxy, the other are vms with several docker containers.
I want to setup a fallback (backup) for one container.
The config of the nginx reverse gateway/proxy containing these machines is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-web.page;
    return       301 http://www.my-web.page$request_uri;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     server_name www.my-web.page;

     location / {
        return 301 https://www.my-web.page$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  my-web.page;
    return       301 https://www.my-web.page$request_uri;

     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my/my-web.page.chained.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my/my-web.page.key.pem; 
}

upstream backend {
            server 192.168.200.210:8030 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=600s;
            server 192.168.200.211:8031 backup;
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my/my-web.page.chained.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my/my-web.page.key.pem;
     server_name www.my-web.page;

    location ~ ^/$ {
    # rewrite only the root page, other urls see next rule
        return 301 https://www.my-web-page-microsite.de/;
    }

     location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;

        # pass to backend-client, failover to second container for the next 5 minutes
            proxy_pass http://backend;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Server-Address  $server_addr;
            proxy_ssl_verify off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
     }

}
```

If something is wrong with my backend-client-servers, nginx won't start.

Isn't there a possibilty to override the check on starting/restarting nginx?